# What term can I use to address my neighbor, if I don't know their name?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I was thinking of りんじんさん or となりさん。Thank you. I did research the term on jisho.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited my answer because I misread the question.

I think there is no specific word to address someone you don't have their name as. (Like mister, ma'am and miss?)  Just start conversation with おはようございます, こんにちは or こんばんは and you can keep talking without referring to their name. This shouldn't be considered impolite. In case you want to know their name, you can say 「すみません，お名前{なまえ}を伺{うかが}ってませんでしたね」 or more simply 「ええっと，お名前{なまえ}は (...) (pause expecting a reply)」

There are several exceptions. If the neighbor is a very old woman (man), you can probably address her (him) as おばあちゃん (おじいちゃん). If the neighbor is a toddler, you can address her (him) as おじょうちゃん (ぼく). If you have a very good friendly relationship with the neighbor and they are apparently much older than you (but not very old), you can probably say おかあさん・おばさん・おばちゃん (female) or おとうさん・おじさん・おっちゃん (male).

隣人{りんじん} (without さん) and お隣{となり}さん (with お) are perfect words when you **speak about** a person (or a family) who lives next door to you. The former is formal and the latter informal. If you want to broaden your scope a little bit, you can say 近所{きんじょ}の人{ひと}  or ご近所{きんじょ}さん to talk about a person in your neighborhood.

Comment: `隣人 (without さん) perfect words to address...` 「おはようございます、隣人。」って話しかけるんですか？

Comment: 英語を読めていないですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます